# How to update libgdx scene2d Label text dynamically?

Tags: java, libgdx

I display a `BitmapFont` on the screen, update its text and the font is updated dynamically on the screen as well.
I seem to fail to do the same with a scene2d `Label` added as actor to a `Stage`.
The `act(delta)` and `draw()` methods are being called in the `render()` method.
My code basically looks as follows:

```
public void init() {
    Label label = new Label(text, labelStyle);
    stage.addActor(label);
}

public void update() {
    updateText(text);
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    /* do some resizing */
    label.setPosition(newPositionX, newPositionY);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    /* do some rendering */
    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
    update();
}
```

Do I need to do anything other than setting the `Label` text, adding it to the `Stage` as actor, and then updating the text elsewhere? The label displays its original text, though the text updating works fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have decided to answer my own question to provide the solution I have come up with, in case someone may find it useful:

I have extended the `Label` class and overridden the `act(float delta)` method of the new custom label:

```
public class CustomLabel extends com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label {
    private String text;

    public CustomLabel(final CharSequence text, final LabelStyle style) {
        super(text, style);
        this.text = text.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void act(final float delta) {
        this.setText(text);
        super.act(delta);
    }

    public void updateText(final String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

The `updateText(String text)` method is then called from outside whenever the text of the label should be updated.

Comment: the updateText(String text) is redundant to setText(String text).

Comment: Agree, drop your custom class and use label.setText directly.

Comment: Another way this can be completed is submitting a task using `Timer() `. Those task are executed in the main loop.

Answer (score 11):

You can  call `.setText("Some String");` on your label in your `Render`-method.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious here? Why is this downvoted as it seems like the most logical way do what's needed?

Comment: maybe because you probably dont want to do it in your render method since its a one off trigger operation.